# docker compose pass host address of another service

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose

I'm struggling with a simple issue with docker-compose, I'm trying to pass the address of my front end to my nginx reverse proxy using the following docker-compose file :

```
version: "3"
services:
  timeline-front:
    image: front-timeline
    restart: on-failure
    depends_on:
      - mongo-app
      - keycloak
      - timeline-back
    environment:
      - KEYCLOAK_SERVEUR=blablabla
      - KEYCLOAK_PORT=8080
    networks:
    - timeline-net
    ports:
    - "8081:80"

  nginx-reverse:
    image: nginx
    depends_on:
      - keycloak
      - timeline-front
      - timeline-back
    volumes:
      - ./data/nginx:/etc/nginx/conf.d
      - ./data/certbot/conf:/etc/letsencrypt
      - ./data/certbot/www:/var/www/certbot
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    environment:
      - FRONT_HOST=timeline-front
      - FRONT_PORT=8081
    networks:
      - timeline-net
    command: /bin/bash -c "envsubst < /etc/nginx/conf.d/app.conf > /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf && exec nginx -g 'daemon off;'"

  certbot:
    image: certbot/certbot
    networks:
      - timeline-net
    volumes:
      - ./data/certbot/conf:/etc/letsencrypt
      - ./data/certbot/www:/var/www/certbot
    entrypoint: "/bin/sh -c 'trap exit TERM; while :; do certbot renew; sleep 12h & wait $${!}; done;'"

networks:
   timeline-net:
```

At the moment I get front_host passed as value to my nginx

any idea ?

Comment: Is this `docker-compose.yml` file on its own an [mcve] – if I had only this one file and ran it, could I reproduce your issue?  What would I see that's not right?

Comment: Try changing `FRONT_PORT=8081` to 80 as your services share same `timeline-net` network. You map 8081 of your host to  port 80  of `timeline-front` service.

Comment: @DavidMaze I can't share the full example, most of the images belongs to a private organisation. still replace timeline-front with any service give the same result.

Comment: @michalk you're right, port should be set to 80 but the issue is more on the host than the port